# Makefile: правильная пересборка .c файлов в случае изменения .h файлов:

Tags: c, makefile

Имеются файлы:

src1.c
src1.**h**
src2.c
src3.c
src4.c
src4.**h**

Стоит обратить внимание, что **НЕ** для всех .c файлов есть свои .h файлы.

Текущий Мakefile работает, но с оговоркой: при изменении **любого** .h файла пересобираются ***ВСЕ*** .c файлы:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
HDRS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HDRS)
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Если раскрыть содержимое переменной $(HDRS), то автоматическая сборка будет выглядеть так:

```
%.o: %.c src1.h src4.h
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Именно поэтому, если изменился только один файл src4.h, то будут пересобраны все *.c файлы.

В другом случае, попытка сделать так, как указано в примере ниже, приведёт к ошибке, потому, что файлы src2.h src3.h не существуют:

```
%.o: %.c %.h
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Будьте любезны, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильный Makefile, чтобы при изменении src4.h пересобирался только src4.с, но не остальные.

Все мои самостоятельные попытки найти ответ на этот вопрос успехом не увенчались.

Заранее благодарю за совет.

Comment: Ну, самое простое - распишите зависимости явно. Вроде такого : src1.o : src1.c src1.h и так далее... Всего четыре строчки - стоит что-то изобретать ?! :-)

Comment: @Sergey, в действительности, файлов под сотню, проект динамично развивается, поэтом интересует только автоматический вариант.

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - используйте cmake - он зависимые хидеры сам определяет.

Comment: Я когда-то пользовался autodepend для автоматической генерации зависимостей.

Comment: @VladD, я так и не понял, как пользоваться autodepend. Официальная документация скудна до безобразия. Примеров в сети == 0;

Comment: @Sergey, СMake тот ещё монстр.

Comment: @DennisV.R.: Я не помню навскидку, но вот тут вроде есть: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend

Comment: **СMake тот ещё монстр** файл для cmake, после файла для make, как русский язык после китайского...  :-) Может быть cmake и монстр, на он понятен, практически, без подготовки. а вот make, чем больше читаешь про него, тем больше запутываешься :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно указать зависимости вручную в Makefile

```
src1.o: src1.c src1.h
```

и так далее для всех объектных файлов.

Или создать файлы зависимостей *.d для всех *.c файлов и включить в Makefile

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
HDRS = $(wildcard *.h)
OBJ_CATALOG=.obj/
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_CATALOG)%.o,$(SRCS))
DEPEND_CATALOG=.depend/
DEPEND=$(patsubst %.c,$(DEPEND_CATALOG)%.d,$(SRCS))

$(OBJ_CATALOG)%.o:%.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(DEPEND_CATALOG)%.d:%.c
    $(CXX) -MM -I. $< | sed -e '1s/^/.obj\//' > $@

include $(DEPEND)
```

Comment: Может, кому станет полезна очень хорошая статья с примерами. Спасибо @Yaroslav, найдена благодаря параметру "-MM":
[Autodependencies with GNU make](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html)

Answer (score 1):

> приведёт к ошибке

не приведёт, если правил будет два. одно с двумя пререквизитами, второе — с одним.

---

пример. для простоты вызывается не компилятор, а программа touch:

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
%.o: %.c %.h
  @echo 'обновился(ись) $?, делаю:'
  touch $@
%.o: %.c
  @echo 'обновился $?, делаю:'
  touch $@
```

создадим только `файл.c`:

```
$ touch файл.c
$ make файл.o
обновился файл.c, делаю:
touch файл.o
```

теперь добавим ещё и `файл.h`:

```
$ touch файл.h
$ make файл.o
обновился(ись) файл.h, делаю:
touch файл.o
```

обратите внимание что сработало **первое** (с двумя пререквизитами) правило. если мы переставим правила местами (первым будет идти правило с одним пререквизитом, а вторым — с двумя), то правило с двумя пререквизитами «не сработает» — *gnu/make* найдёт первое подходящее правило и на этом «успокоится».

обновим оба файла — `файл.c` и `файл.h`:

```
$ touch файл.c файл.h
$ make файл.o
обновился(ись) файл.c файл.h, делаю:
touch файл.o
```

ну и напоследок, если ни один исходный файл не обновлялся, то:

```
$ make файл.o
make: «файл.o» не требует обновления.
```

Comment: Отличный вариант! Однако пример, приведённый @Yaroslav более универсален. Он работает даже в том случае, если имя файла .c и .h не совпадают. Там достаточно использовать #include одного в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Немного запоздал, но почему не простой `patsubst`:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
HDRS = $(wildcard *.h)
SRCS_W_HDRS := $(patsubst %.h, %.c, $(HDRS))

$(SRCS_W_HRDS): %.c: %.h
```

Comment: Лучше позже, чем никогда ) Спасибо за интересный вариант!